# Ignore directory or filename when using Yara -r

Tags: rules, malware

Does anyone know how to instruct Yara to ignore scanning a certain directory or filename when using a recursive scan? The issue is when my scan completes, there are hits from the rule file itself, so I want to instruct Yara to ignore the directory the rules file sits in

for example - i want to scan c:\ recursively but ignore directory c:\users\xyz\documents\rules.yar

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately YARA doesn't have that feature, but as a workaround you can define your strings as hexadecimal instead of text. For example, instead of:

$ = "hello"

Use:

$ = { 68 65 6C 6C 6F }

Alternatively you can escape one character of the string:

$ = "\x68ello"

This is far from ideal and only makes sense if you have a simple rule.